# How does forehead cooling affect me?

Tags: headache, eyelids, cold-compress, forehead

Sometimes I have headaches. I've heard that they're caused by the pressure of veins in my brain (not anything more). I found out that if I cool my forehead or eyelids with water, the pain stops.

Am I actually healing the cause or just cloaking the symptoms?

(It does not hurry, I'm just interested ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly reducing some of the causes of the symptoms, but for numerous reasons and maybe a secondary diagnosis the headaches themselves may return. Head cooling is a typical treatment for headaches and migraines.

[Migraines- Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/migraine-headache/in-depth/migraines/art-20047242)

> Ice packs have a
>   numbing effect, which may dull the sensation of pain.

Heat works as well.

> Hot packs and  heating pads can relax tense muscles. Warm showers or baths may have a
>   similar effect.

[How it works possibly:](https://www.excedrin.com/migraines/treatment/ice-pack-for-migraines/)

- > It is thought that cold constricts the blood vessels (a process known
  >   as vasoconstriction), possibly creating decreased downstream blood
  >   flow and lessening the pain you may feed. A cold pack may also reduce
  >   edema (swelling).
- > The potential neurologic effects of cold therapy on migraine may be
  >   rooted in the fact that the cold inhibits your ability to feel the
  >   pain, a process called analgesia.

So applying cold is not just masking the symptoms, but may also be working at the root of the problem.